# Cannot retrieve selected lookups using the OData endpoint

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata, dynamics-crm-365

I'm unable to retrieve lookup fields when filtering an OData Request.

I used the following requests :

````
https://mycrm.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)?$select=contactid,ownerid,createdby,new_expirefin,new_testcumul_stat```
````

This request retrieves contactid, new_expirefin, and new_testcumul_stat, but no trace of ownerid and createdby.

In another hand, this request:

```
https://mycrm.api.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)
```

return all fields, including those missing on the other request. Lookups are sent as Guid.

Both request uses the

```
Prefer = odata.include-annotations="*"
```

header. Knowing I cannot know which column are lookups (I'm working on a generic library), how could I retrieve those lookups ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the format `_lookupName_value` allows you to retrieve the lookups:

`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/contacts(guid)?$select=contactid,fullname,_ownerid_value,_createdby_value`

Which of course leaves the problem of knowing which fields are lookups and thus need this formatting.

This can help:
`https://myOrg.api.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')?$select=LogicalName&$expand=ManyToOneRelationships($select=ReferencingAttribute,ReferencedEntity)`

Comment: Works well, I used this to write a metadata caching mechanism I query every time a request is done. Not the most efficient, but work well.